# Is it possible to download the database backup files from a vault in Azure?

Tags: azure

We have a virtual machine in Azure running SQL server. I have configured Azure Backup to backup the database on a schedule and it works great.

From time to time we need a copy of nearly up-to-date data on local machines (outside of azure). It would be great if we could just download one of the full backup files straight from the vault, but I cannot find any way of doing that.

Is there anyway to access the database backup files in a Recovery Services vault?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there isn't a way to restore/access the database backup files. Please reach out to AskAzureBackupTeam@microsoft.com for more details on a proposed solution that the product team intends to release by end of 2019.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh I have reached out to them. For anyone trying to achieve the same thing, we are currently (and have been for years) using sqlbak.com to back up the database on a schedule and put the backups into Azure blob storage which we can access at will. But it would be nice to not have to rely on a 3rd party tool (even if it is very good!).